# Getting error while Parsing the XML data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I was trying to get the google Weather Data as below:

```
try
        {
            string cityName = txtCityName.Text;
            //Format the google URL with CityName
            string weatherURL = string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather={0}", cityName);

            //Parse the XML URL and get the Data 
            var weatherXML = XDocument.Parse(weatherURL);
            var weatherResult = from weatherDetail in weatherXML.Descendants("current_conditions")
                                select new currentWeatherCondition
                                {
                                    condition = ((string)weatherDetail.Element("condition").Attribute("data")).Trim(),
                                    temp = ((string)weatherDetail.Element("temp_c").Attribute("data")).Trim(),
                                    imageURL = ((string)weatherDetail.Element("icon").Attribute("data")).Trim(),

                                };


        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Response.Write(err.Message.ToString());
        }
```

I am getting the exception **Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. ** as I am not passing the XML data but URL. How can I pass the XML data into the parser

Answer (score 2):

Parse is expecting a string filled with XML

Either use XDocument.load (which i think will take a url), or get the xml string using a webrequest and pass that in